# Can I use SIMD to speed up my image resize function and maybe avoid the nested loop?

Tags: c++, image-processing, x86, sse, simd

I have a resize function that uses a nested for loop to resize a picture with bilinear interpolation and merge it with a background image.

For an image with the size of 320x240 that would result in 76800 cycles.

Regarding to this article [Using SIMD Technologies on Intel® Architecture to Speed Up Game Code](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-simd-technologies-on-intel-architecture-to-speed-up-game-code) it should be possible to speed up the whole process by 4 times.

Does this mean I am able to use only one loop to iterate over the height and fill the whole width at once?

The current implementation took 1ms on an Intel i7 and 3 to 4 ms on an Intel Atom x7. Because the Atom is supporting SSE 4.2 too I was thinking about taking benefits of it.

But to be honest I have no idea how I should write my code to achieve this. Is this even possible for my use case?

Thank you in advance!

C++ code

```
void Resize24Bpp(BYTE* pd, int* pixels, int widthSource, int heightSource, int width, int height, BYTE* baseImage)
{
    float xs = (float)widthSource / width;
    float ys = (float)heightSource / height;

    float fracx, fracy, ifracx, ifracy, sx, sy, l0, l1, rf, gf, bf;
    int c, x0, x1, y0, y1;
    BYTE c1a, c1r, c1g, c1b, c2a, c2r, c2g, c2b, c3a, c3r, c3g, c3b, c4a, c4r, c4g, c4b;
    BYTE a, r, g, b;

    // Bilinear
    int srcIdx = 0;
    int baseIdx = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            sx = x * xs;
            sy = y * ys;
            x0 = (int)sx;
            y0 = (int)sy;

            // Calculate coordinates of the 4 interpolation points
            fracx = sx - x0;
            fracy = sy - y0;
            ifracx = 1.0f - fracx;
            ifracy = 1.0f - fracy;
            x1 = x0 + 1;
            if (x1 >= widthSource)
            {
                x1 = x0;
            }
            y1 = y0 + 1;
            if (y1 >= heightSource)
            {
                y1 = y0;
            }

            // Read source color
            c = pixels[y0 * widthSource + x0];
            c1a = (BYTE)(c >> 24);
            c1r = (BYTE)(c >> 16);
            c1g = (BYTE)(c >> 8);
            c1b = (BYTE)(c);

            c = pixels[y0 * widthSource + x1];
            c2a = (BYTE)(c >> 24);
            c2r = (BYTE)(c >> 16);
            c2g = (BYTE)(c >> 8);
            c2b = (BYTE)(c);

            c = pixels[y1 * widthSource + x0];
            c3a = (BYTE)(c >> 24);
            c3r = (BYTE)(c >> 16);
            c3g = (BYTE)(c >> 8);
            c3b = (BYTE)(c);

            c = pixels[y1 * widthSource + x1];
            c4a = (BYTE)(c >> 24);
            c4r = (BYTE)(c >> 16);
            c4g = (BYTE)(c >> 8);
            c4b = (BYTE)(c);

            // Calculate colors
            // Alpha
            l0 = ifracx * c1a + fracx * c2a;
            l1 = ifracx * c3a + fracx * c4a;
            a = (BYTE)(ifracy * l0 + fracy * l1);

            // Write destination
            if (a > 0)
            {
                // Red
                l0 = ifracx * c1r + fracx * c2r;
                l1 = ifracx * c3r + fracx * c4r;
                rf = ifracy * l0 + fracy * l1;

                // Green
                l0 = ifracx * c1g + fracx * c2g;
                l1 = ifracx * c3g + fracx * c4g;
                gf = ifracy * l0 + fracy * l1;

                // Blue
                l0 = ifracx * c1b + fracx * c2b;
                l1 = ifracx * c3b + fracx * c4b;
                bf = ifracy * l0 + fracy * l1;

                // Cast to BYTE
                float alpha = a / 255.0f;
                r = (BYTE)((rf * alpha) + (baseImage[baseIdx] * (1.0f - alpha)));
                g = (BYTE)((gf * alpha) + (baseImage[baseIdx] * (1.0f - alpha)));
                b = (BYTE)((bf * alpha) + (baseImage[baseIdx] * (1.0f - alpha)));

                pd[srcIdx++] = b;
                pd[srcIdx++] = g;
                pd[srcIdx++] = r;
            }
            else
            {
                // Red, Green, Blue     
                pd[srcIdx++] = baseImage[baseIdx];
                pd[srcIdx++] = baseImage[baseIdx];
                pd[srcIdx++] = baseImage[baseIdx];
            }

            baseIdx++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this, and you should see a significant speed-up (but first check that your compiler is not already auto-vectorizing your code!). Ask yourself whether you actually need to make the code faster though, as everything comes at a price: SIMD optimisation results in code which is less portable, more complex, harder to maintain, and possibly less robust. It also takes time and effort to write it. So, if you genuinely need better performance then go for it, otherwise leave it alone and focus on some other task.

Comment: See: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14659612/253056) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5962408/253056) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26467744/253056)

Comment: If you do this, remember to keep the original code around as a baseline for testing. Write a unit test that checks that the original and SIMD code produce the same result for various inputs.

Comment: @PaulR Thank you for this links. I looked through the code but I have no idea what am I seeing here. Does these example do resizing aswell?

Comment: @datoml: the linked questions just cover bilinear interpolation using SIMD. If you study these you can get a feel for the sort of effort that might be involved in (a) learning SIMD programming techniques and (b) implementing a SIMD version of your resize function. As I said above, it's  a cost/benefit trade-off: how much you need the extra speed versus how much sacrifice you're prepared to make in order to get it. ;-)

Comment: @PaulR It seems so :). I will try to get my head around it. I played a bit with a code example and achieved a 0ms execution. Mine took 2ms for instance. So I think its worth the cost.

Comment: Usually it's just a commercial decision whether to optimise or not, but in your case it would have a beneficial side-effect in that you would learn some SIMD programming in the process, which you might be able to put to good use in the future. Take a read through the `[sse]` and `[simd]` tags here on StackOverflow - there are a lot of good answers and code examples which you can learn from. Good luck !

Comment: Instead of going straight to Intel intrinsics, you may want to consider helping the compiler auto-vectorize the code first. If you're using GCC, ICC, PGI, or a few others (notably absent: MSVC and clang) OpenMP is a great way to go, http://primeurmagazine.com/repository/PrimeurMagazine-AE-PR-12-14-32.pdf is the best intro I've seen.

Comment: @nemequ Thank you for this tip. I'll have a look at it tomorrow :).

Comment: @PaulR Thank you for your help. I will start with the basics first to get a feel for it. Thank you :).

Comment: @nemequ: compilers are often bad at auto-vectorizing code with shuffles and conversions to different data widths.  When they do auto-vectorize, it's often a lot worse than what careful manual vectorization could do.  Worth trying, but don't get your hopes up.